# Eclipse complains about recursive function call

Tags: c++, class, implementation

A simple binary search tree class declaration:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

// Provides various structures utilized by search algorithms.

// Represents an generalized node with integer value and a set of children.
class Node {
protected:
    std::vector<Node*> children;
    int value;
public:
    //Creates a new instance of a Node with a default value=-1.
    Node(){value = -1;}
    //Creates a new instance of a Node with a specified value.
    explicit Node(int value){this->value = value;}
    virtual ~Node(){delete children;}

    //Adds new Node with specified value to the list of child nodes. Multiple
    //children with the same value are allowed.
    //Returns added node.
    virtual Node* Insert(int value);
    //Removes first occurrence of a Node with specified value among children.
    virtual void Remove(int value);
};

// Represents a binary search tree node with at most two children.
class BTNode: public Node {
public:
    //Creates a new instance of a BTNode with a default value=-1.
    BTNode():Node(){}
    //Creates a new instance of a BTNode with a specified value.
    explicit BTNode(int value):Node(value){}

    //Adds new BTNode with specified value to the list of child nodes in an
    //ordered manner, that is right child value is >= value of this node and
    //left child value < value of this node.
    virtual BTNode* Insert(int value);
    //Removes first occurrence of a Node with specified value from the tree.
    virtual void Remove(int value);
    //Returns a node with specified value.
    virtual BTNode* Search(int value);
};
```

And eclipse complains about it's definition:

```
BTNode* BTNode::Search(int value){
    if (this->value == value) return *this;

    //Determines whether value is in left(0) or right(1) child.
    int child = this->value > value ? 0 : 1;
    if (children[child] != NULL)
        return children[child]->Search(value);

    return NULL;
}
```

exactly where the call `children[child]->Search(value)` takes place with a message "method Search could not be resolved". **Build runs just fine (no compilation errors whatsoever)**.  What's the problem with that?

P.S.:Haven't tried running the code,yet. Working on it.

Comment: You say Eclipse complains.  Is that during compilation or just when it tries to parse your code to analyze it for auto-completion and the like?

Comment: @JohnZwinck, added more details. So it's the second option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Search` is part of the `BTNode` interface but it is not part of `Node`s interface, `children` is a `vector` of `Node*` so it is not valid to call `Search` on a `Node *`. If it makes sense for `Node` to have a `Search` method then adding it to `Node` would fix that issue. If not then you need to rethink your design and that is probably beyond the scope of this question.

There are also a few other issues. You have:

```
virtual ~Node(){delete children;}
```

but `children` is not a `pointer` it is a `std::vector<Node*>`. You need to iterate over the `vector` and call `delete` each element. In `Search` you have this:

```
if (this->value == value) return *this;
```

but `Search` returns a `BTNode*` so it should be:

```
if (this->value == value)  return this ;
```

Comment: Makes sense. Can you please suggest design improvements or best practices for my purposes? (I'm rather new to c++)

Comment: Do I get it correctly that I need to iterate over the vector of pointers and call delete for each pointer?

Comment: @DenysS. Just updated answer, you need to iterate over the `vector` and call `delete` on each element